# Deletion of volume snapshot created for unattached PVC is taking long time

Tags: kubernetes, snapshot, persistent-volumes

We are adding snapshot feature in our driver and right now doing few tests before release. I have below scenario to execute

1. Create PVC
2. Create Snapshot from PVC
3. Snapshot should not go to Ready State [ as PVC is not attached to any instance ]
4. Delete Snapshot
5. Delete PVC

I see that step 4 is taking time for execution.

```
Sun May  1 21:48:59 IST 2022
volumesnapshot.snapshot.storage.k8s.io "snapshot-csi-block-pvc-custom" deleted
Sun May  1 22:02:10 IST 2022
```

Is this expected. Could someone please explain

Comment: May be there is dependency like snapshot class etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the snapshot anyway first patch it and then delete it.